# Attribute Error at/ 'str' object has no attribute 'makefile'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm learning Django and got this error in my first code itself.

[image: what's wrong in this code]

I was trying for just Hello world type of program using Django, everything was perfect but got this error 'str' object has no attribute 'makefile'

[image]

Comment: Post your code as text and not as images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `HTTPResponse` from somewhere (http.client?) (I guess on line 1 of your script)

`django.http` has only `HttpResponse`. Try:

```
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```